# Question about compact subsets contained in an open set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space, let $\{K_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ be a family of compact subsets. Let $U$ be an open set containing $\cap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} K_\lambda$. Prove that there exists a finite subset of indices $\Lambda_0 \subset \Lambda$ such that $\cap_{\lambda \in \Lambda_0} K_\lambda$.

This question confuses me because isn't this always true? I'm mainly looking for intuition here, or someone to help show me what I'm not understanding. Once I get started on it I will post my progress, in which case I may also need a bit of help along the way. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question. There is a  finite subset .... such that ?????.

Comment: Sorry about that! I fixed it.

Comment: I am unable too the corrected question even after I guessed what the question was about and posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want $\cap_{\{\lambda \in \Lambda_0\}} K_{\lambda} \subset U$. To prove this let $C_{\lambda} =U^{c} \cap K_{\lambda}$. Then $C_{\lambda}$ is  a collection of compact sets with empty intersection. So it cannot have finite intersection property which means some finite intersection must be empty, say $\cap_{\{\lambda \in \Lambda_0\}} (K_{\lambda}\cap U^{c}) =\emptyset$. This implies that $\cap_{\{\lambda \in \Lambda_0\}} K_{\lambda} \subset U$.

Comment: Ohh, I understand what the question is asking now. Thank you for your help!